# Changing portal page layout depending on the user

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal, page-layout

Is it possible to change the portal page layout depending on the user on WebSphere portal? For example, I have 2 portlets A and B. For user 1, I want portlet A to appear above portlet B and for user 2, I want the reverse, ie, portlet B should appear above portlet A. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe easiest to use two different pages. One will have your layout for user 1 and the other page for user 2. Then use access control or personalization to direct each user to the intended page. Which option to use will depend on how you decide which users should see which layout.

Comment: But is there any way to actually change the page layout without using different pages?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to change the layout of a page based on the user, or based on anything other than what you specify when you create the page..